# Cache error in error_get_last function?

Tags: php

I'm inspecting an open source web application. There's aproblem that it used error_get_last function as in this code

```
$last_error = error_get_last();
if($last_error['type'] === E_ERROR || $last_error['type'] === E_PARSE) {
  include 'error.php';
}
if (ob_get_length()) ob_end_flush();
```

It annoys me because it seem that it cache old error of the old code however the edited code doesn't have any error. Therefore it display old error for a while. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks for any help

**Edit:** I show the function __shutdown() where the code run in the end of a request

```
function __shutdown() {
    $logger_session = Logger::getSession();
    if (($logger_session instanceof Logger_Session) && !$logger_session->isEmpty()) {
      Logger::saveSession();
    } // if
    $last_error = error_get_last();
    if($last_error['type'] === E_ERROR || $last_error['type'] === E_PARSE) {
      include 'error.php';
    }
    if (ob_get_length()) ob_end_flush();
  } // __shutdown
```

Comment: Is it popular open source web application? Can we know the name of open source?

Comment: @Zerkms: If I edited the code and it generated some errors, I fixed those errors but those errors still appeared.

Comment: @Singh: projectpier.org/

Comment: @coolkid: then they are there, obviously.

Comment: @zerkm: In the showed error, it display the error for the old code.

Comment: @coolkid: then you did not change it. There is no miracle.

Comment: I know what you mean, I think the problem is somewhere that I don't understand about function error_get_last()

Comment: in the line: $last_error = error_get_last(); The last error is the error of the old code, however I fixed that error in the running code. I don't know why it happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `error_get_last` does not cache anything, it's just a function like `substr` and all the others. If what you see seems to be cached, the cacheing happens at a different place. Maybe you are editing the wrong file (or you didn't really fix the error), have an opcode or output cache or whatever.

Comment: could you please install the ProjectPier and test it by add some invalid code to see the error, after that remove the invalid code to return to stable version, then will you still see the error?

Comment: I don't need to install it. `error_get_last` is a builtin PHP function that reports the last error that occured. If you fix the code so that no error occurs during the processing of your request, this function returns NULL. The manual doesn't lie.

Comment: Does it mean that the last error of the last PHP script? So therefore we cannot use this method for get the error of the running PHP script at the end of the script, right? because it may return the old error of old code in development environment, right?

Comment: No, the interpreter does not know anything about the last script it executed, not even which one it was. In this terms PHP is as stateless as HTTP. If you get the same error as last time although this error is definitely fixed, you are getting a cached version of the page. This cached page could come from an output cache or could be generated by cached opcode.

Comment: You should try it by your self, you will see that error_get_last returns the last error of PHP intepreter. That means this error may belong to the last script which generated this error

Comment: If that'd be true, it would also work that way in every other script. But it does not. I checked it.